# Escape parentheses in NLTK parse tree

Tags: python, regex, parsing, nlp, nltk

In NLTK we can convert a parentheses tree into an actual Tree object. However, when a token contains parentheses, the parsing is not what you would expect since NLTK parses those parentheses as a new node.

As an example, take the sentence

> They like(d) it a lot

This could be parsed as

```
(S (NP (PRP They)) (VP like(d) (NP (PRP it)) (NP (DT a) (NN lot))) (. .))
```

But if you parse this with NLTK into a tree, and output it - it is clear that the `(d)` is parsed as a new node, which is no surprise.

```py
from nltk import Tree

s = '(S (NP (PRP They)) (VP like(d) (NP (PRP it)) (NP (DT a) (NN lot))) (. .))'

tree = Tree.fromstring(s)
print(tree)
```

The result is

```
(S
  (NP (PRP They))
  (VP like (d ) (NP (PRP it)) (NP (DT a) (NN lot)))
  (. .))
```

So `(d )` is a node inside the VP rather than part of the token `like`. Is there a way in the tree parser to escape parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially I thought this was not possible ... but halfway through writing my answer I found a solution. However the solution is quite messy so I have left my original answer with a slightly better solution.

`nltk` allows you to provide custom regexes so you can write a regex to match escaped parentheses. The regex `([^\s\(\)\\]+(\\(?=\()\([^\s\(\)\\]+\\(?=\))\))*[\\]*)+` will match parentheses escaped by backslashes (`\`). This however, will include the escaping backslashes in each leaf so you must write a leaf function to remove these. The following code will properly parse it:

```py
from nltk import Tree

s = '(S (NP (PRP They)) (VP like\(d\) (NP (PRP it)) (NP (DT a) (NN lot))) (. .))'

tree = Tree.fromstring(s, leaf_pattern=r"([^\s\(\)\\]+(\\(?=\()\([^\s\(\)\\]+\\(?=\))\))*[\\]*)+", read_leaf=lambda x: x.replace("\\(", "(").replace("\\)", ")"))
print(tree)
```

And it outputs:

```
(S
  (NP (PRP They))
  (VP like(d) (NP (PRP it)) (NP (DT a) (NN lot)))
  (. .))
```

---

## Original answer

Perhaps you could ask `nltk` to match another bracket:

```py
from nltk import Tree

s = '[S [NP [PRP They]] [VP like(d) [NP [PRP it]] [NP [DT a] [NN lot]]] [. .]]'

tree = Tree.fromstring(s, brackets='[]')
print(tree)
```

Which prints out:

```
(S
  (NP (PRP They))
  (VP like(d) (NP (PRP it)) (NP (DT a) (NN lot)))
  (. .))
```

---

You can get different brackets by using the `pformat` method (which is called internally when you call print):

```py
print(tree.pformat(parens='[]'))
```

Which prints out:

```
[S
  [NP [PRP They]]
  [VP like(d) [NP [PRP it]] [NP [DT a] [NN lot]]]
  [. .]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The traditional method is to convert parentheses into `-LRB-` and `-RRB-` within the parse. Most tools that work with Penn Treebank data support this escaping (NLTK, CoreNLP and many others).

NLTK supports this, but its default PTB-style tokenization assumes the parentheses are separate tokens rather than potentially token-internal:

```
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordTokenizer, TreebankWordDetokenizer

t = TreebankWordTokenizer()
d = TreebankWordDetokenizer()

s = "They like(d) it a lot."

tokens = t.tokenize(s, convert_parentheses=True)
print("Tokens:", tokens)
detokenized = d.detokenize(tokens, convert_parentheses=True)
print("Detokenized:", detokenized)
```

Output:

```
Tokens: ['They', 'like', '-LRB-', 'd', '-RRB-', 'it', 'a', 'lot', '.']
Detokenized: They like (d) it a lot.
```

If you convert the parentheses on your own in your input data without inserting extra spaces, the default tokenization and the detokenization with `convert_parentheses=True` work:

```
s = 'They like-LRB-d-RRB- it a lot.'
tokens = t.tokenize(s)
print("Tokens:", tokens)
detokenized = d.detokenize(tokens, convert_parentheses=True)
print("Detokenized:", detokenized)
```

Output:

```
Tokens: ['They', 'like-LRB-d-RRB-', 'it', 'a', 'lot', '.']
Detokenized: They like(d) it a lot.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you give a little bit of information of how these tokens can then be used as a parse tree? Tokenising is of course only just the first step since I need the sentence's parse tree.

Comment: Well, if your tagger hasn't seen any tokens like this before you might get inaccurate tags and parses, but you should be able to represent the tokens/parse without any technical difficulties. With tokens like this, the PTB tagset isn't even sufficient: what is the tag for `like(d)`?